# Breaker trips after electrical work, should I fit a bigger breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I took out 2 walls in my kitchen. Deleted 2 3way switches. Created a junction box in my crawl space. Flipped the power and everything worked. A few hours later I turned my garage light on and it tripped the breaker. It's the main line in from the breaker panel. It's also a 15 amp breaker. I've got 6 switches on the circuit. Should I change the breaker to a 20 amp?

Comment: Nope.  You've made a wiring mistake.    Increasing a breaker size is not dependent on need, it's dependent on the size of the wire only.

Comment: ^^That^^. Can you provide pics of the new junction box?

Comment: where do people get this idea to use a larger breaker? It's a very bad idea.  We'd need to know a lot more detail about this, e.g. is the garage light on the same circuit as the altered wiring, was it formerly on a 3-way, how were the messengers handled in the removed 3-way, were the unused wires capped or just left to dangle, etc.

Comment: @Harper putting in a larger breaker usually prevents the tripping "problem".  Unfortunately, it has the side effect of burning down the house.  People do it for the same reason they used to use pennies as fuses. They don't know any better.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was actually a ground wire that was too close to the hot line on the switch. I pulled it and re adjusted it. I followed the original way it was wired. Only difference was I eliminated the red and black,and capped and taped them, from an old 3 way switch that wast a 12-3 wire. Thx again

Comment: Yup, ground wires and side screws will getcha everytime :) Confined space in those boxes!

Comment: You seem to have solved your problem. Consider adding what you did as an answer to your own question. I'd probably upvote it.